# Creating customized info windows for a Marker when using a cluster manager?

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I was following this [guide](https://www.zoftino.com/google-maps-android-custom-info-window-example), until I realized that he was adding marker directly to the map and not letting a cluster manager handle it.

I created a `CustomInfo` class that implements `InfoWindowAdapter`. In the `getInfoContents(Marker marker)` I get the data from the marker using `getTag()`. The problem is that I never set a tag to my marker (where would I?).

This is the code for when I read in my location objects:

```
private void generateShelterObjects()
{

    Log.i(TAG, "METHOD generateShelterObjects() STARTED");

    InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.shelters_csv_file);
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(is, Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
    String line = "";

    try {
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            // Split the line into different tokens (using the comma as a separator).
            String[] tokens = line.split(",");

            String address = tokens[0];
            double latitude = Double.parseDouble(tokens[1]);
            double longitude = Double.parseDouble(tokens[2]);
            LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
            String numberOfOccupants = tokens[3];

            MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title(address).snippet("Antal platser: " + numberOfOccupants);

            ShelterObject obj = new ShelterObject(latLng, address, numberOfOccupants);

            listMarkers.add(markerOptions);

        }

    } catch (IOException e1) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Error" + line, e1);
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

To add markers to the map I use this method for my cluster manager:

```
private void addClusterItems()
{

    for (MarkerOptions markerOptions : listMarkers) {

        ShelterObject clusterItem = new ShelterObject(markerOptions.getPosition(), markerOptions.getTitle(), markerOptions.getSnippet());

        clusterManager.addItem(clusterItem);
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Check this,

```
private void setUpcustomInfoWindow(){
    myMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter() {
        @Override
        public View getInfoWindow(Marker arg0) {
            return null;
        }
        @Override
        public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {
            View myContentView =getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(
                    R.layout.custom_info_window, null);
            TextView tvAddress = ((TextView) myContentView
                    .findViewById(R.id.tv_address_info_window));
            TextView tvAveragePrice = ((TextView) myContentView
                    .findViewById(R.id.tv_averageprice_info_window));
            TextView tvAverageSqft = ((TextView) myContentView
                    .findViewById(R.id.tv_averagesqft_info_window));
            MicroLocality microLocality = (MicroLocality) marker.getTag();
            tvAddress.setText(microLocality.getMicroLocality());
            tvAveragePrice.setText(getActivity().getString(R.string.Rs)+" "+microLocality.getPricerange());
            tvAverageSqft.setText(getActivity().getString(R.string.Rs)+" "+microLocality.getPricePerSqft());
            return myContentView;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I'm still not associating any data with the markers, so this doesn't work. The marker getInfoContents() gets has no tag associated with it.

Here's my class: https://pastebin.com/qyVu1bjj